# Multiple order to one receipt, select clause with no redundant results, how?

Tags: sql, sql-server

2 table: tb_order, tb_receipt. One receipt from 3-4 sales orders. But only orders with the same code, name can be combined into one receipt.
So I want to write a select clause that select most fields in tb_receipt and name, code from tb_order, but using inner join will only produce redundant results, how do I deal with it?

```
tb_order: receiptid, name, code, product, total

tb_receipt: receiptid, sum
```

I can only think of join:

```
   select a.sum, b.code, b.name from tb_reciept a inner join tb_order b on a.receiptid = b.receiptid
```

But that will give me redundant result as one receipt may takes in several order.

Sample data: tb_order :

```
receiptid   code   name   total

201601      001  iphone5  100

201601      001  iphone5  500

201601      001  iphone5  300
```

tb_receipt:

```
receiptid  sum

201601     900
```

expect:

```
receiptid  code  name      sum

201601     001   iphone5   900
```

Comment: What have you tried? What does you data look like? All the standard questions...

Comment: Please show sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a reference from tb_order to tb_receipt by foreign key tb_order.receipt_id, you can use

```
select distinct tb_receipt.*, tb_order.code, tb_order.name
from tb_receipt inner join tb_order on tb_order.receipt_id = tb_receipt.id
where <...>
```

or more effectively

```
select tb_receipt.*, o.code, o.name
from tb_receipt inner join (
  select distinct code, name, receipt_id from tb_order where <...>
) as o on o.receipt_id = tb_receipt.id
```